# Event Driven design tool

Tags: node.js, event-driven

Recently I have been experimenting with node.js and I find its event-driven nature very nice. I was wandering if there are any tools for event-driven design, preferably open source. Do you know/use any? Something which would visualize the possible application flow paths would be really good.

Comment: What would be the use of such tools?

Comment: IMHO, help me design better an application. As it gets more complicated I sometimes lose track.

Comment: [nCore](https://github.com/Raynos/nCore) could be used as a "design tool". It enforces an Event driven architecture. In terms of visual design tools, no there aren't any. What would you expect them to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few tools:

- [Servoy](http://java.dzone.com/articles/do-you-know-about-servoy)
- [Visual WebGUI](https://www.componentsource.com/product/visual-webgui)
- [Maqetta](http://maqetta.org/)

[Servoy](https://www.servoyforge.net/projects/servoy-codeeditor/repository) is dual licensed, with a commercial license for commercial development as well as an AGPL license for the Eclipse plugin and [non-commercial development](https://wiki.servoy.com/display/DOCS/Open+Source+FAQ). Visual WebGUI has a [LGPLv2 license](https://nethtml5.codeplex.com/license). [Maqetta](https://github.com/maqetta/maqetta/blob/master/LICENSE) is dual licensed as well, with an APL license for commercial development and a BSD license for non-commercial development.